# Average degree of non-convex polyhedra.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Average degree for any convex polyhedra is strictly less than 6. Does this fact stand for any non-convex polyhedra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know if this can ever be violated for non-convex polyhedra, since it's pretty easy to satisfy even for a non-convex polyhedron; for example, take an icosahedron and "punch in" a vertex, making a concave polyhedron with the same skeleton graph.

Alternatively, [Jessen's icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessen%27s_icosahedron) is a concave polyhedron with $20$ triangular faces, so it has average degree $5$ just like the ordinary icosahedron.

To violate the inequality, take the [Császár polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron): it has $7$ vertices, any two of which are connected by an edge, so it has average degree exactly $6$.

If we want average degree strictly greater than $6$, we'll need a polyhedron with genus at least $2$. The reason is Euler characteristic: we have
$$
   V - E + F = 2 - 2g
$$
and $3F \le 2E$ since all faces are at most triangular, which means that the average degree $\frac{2E}{V}$ is at most $6 + \frac{12(g-1)}{V}$, where $g$ is the genus.

I'm not aware of any named polyhedra of this type, but [Wikipedia shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_polyhedron#/media/File:Eight_octahedra_toroid.png) a way to combine octahedra into a toroidal polyhedron; put two of these together and you get a polyhedron with genus $2$ and only triangular faces. Then the inequality $3F \le 2E$ will be tight, and you'll get a polyhedron with average degree (slightly) larger than $6$.

Comment: Does there exist a polyhedra with strictly greater average degree than 6?

Comment: See the update to my answer.